# BIRT: Computing the average of a time interval

Tags: birt, postgresql

I have the following database table consisting of a series of tasks:

```
id BIGINT NOT NULL
time_in timestamp(0) with time zone,
time_out timestamp(0) with time zone,
user_name text NOT NULL
```

I compute the duration of a task as (time_out - time_in). I need to first compute the average task duration for a given user, and afterwards for all users.

I do the first within the SQL query used to obtain the data set. The result of this is an INTERVAL, but in BIRT it is seen as a String (maybe because the INTERVAL data type is absent).

So now I have a set of Strings, each representing an INTERVAL. How do I compute their average?

P.S. I first thought I should do this by using the BIRT 'Time' data type. However, 'Time' represents a time of day, not an interval. There seems to be not equivalent for INTERVAL in BIRT.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the second average using SQL as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the avg aggregate function?

SELECT avg(time_out - time_in) as user_avg FROM tasks WHERE user_name='bob';

SELECT avg(time_out - time_in) as all_avg FROM tasks;

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with birt, but I'd think the best way would be to let PostgreSQL do it. Define a view that does your averaging, and just SELECT from it.